# SQL or Excel solution to clean up a report

Tags: sql, excel, report, data-cleaning

I have a transaction report which has data as follows:

```
Description.      Debit.      Credit.
Txn A.              15
Txn A.              15
Txn A.              15
Txn B.              20
Txn B.              10
Txn B.              10
Txn B.                          20
Txn A.                          15
Txn C.                          40
```

I want my output to filter out (remove) any transactions that appear in Debit entry and have a matching Credit entry (cancel out each other).
So resulting table would be

```
Description.       Debit.     Credit.
Txn A.              15
Txn A.              15
Txn B.              10
Txn B.              10
Txn C.                          40
```

Note:
If there are multiple entries for Txn A that don't have a match in the 2nd column, I don't want to combine them into 1 row.

i.e. Only cancel out the one 15 entry that matched. 
and the Order of the 15 entry doesn't matter so any one of the entries can be canceled.

Need to do this either in excel or using a SQL query.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, what is the format of the transaction report? Excel file? SQL table? CSV file?...

Comment: It's a csv file, I can load it into SQL, or Excel and do the transformations in either. Am thinking it will be easier to do this in SQL though. @MeirGabay thoughts? Thank you for taking the time to help out on this!